# How to create custom authentication with Laravel on an existing default authentication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm curently completing my job, but my client is requested more feature on managing users, like suspending an account, or freezing an account, I'm very sure it can be done easily with this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users, but I'm already using default `php artisan make:auth` Authentication. My question is, It's posible to add more check while user logging in like, `if active == true` or something like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel 5.4, You can use `authenticated` post login hook of `AuthenticatesUsers` to do your custom validation.

```
protected function authenticated( Request $request, $user ) {

    if($user->active){
         return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()); 
    }

    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->back()
                     ->withInput($request->except('password'))
                     ->withError('Please activate your account.')
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I'm interested to this answer than another one, But Where should I put the code you gave? On the LoginController??

Comment: Yes. Check your `LoginController`, there must be `use AuthenticatesUsers` statement. So you are just overriding the `authenticated` method of `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

Comment: I paste whole code you gave into the LoginController , But no different User still can login even active is false :/

Comment: @RizalFakhri What is your database field for active flag?

Comment: Worked Perfectly! ^_^ Thanks!

Comment: `$table->boolean('active');` this.

Comment: Hey Got 1 problem again,,, The errors message is not displayed, and not detected on `$errors->count()` I have no idea about that.

Comment: Solved with: `$errors->has()` and `$errors->first()` Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

you can over ride the existing login function by your own like this:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    // This section is the only change
    if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
        $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
        if ($user->active) {
            Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        } else {
            return redirect($this->loginPath()) // Change this to redirect elsewhere
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'active' => 'You must be active to login.'
                ]);
        }
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);

}
```

And you can also do modifications as per your need.

Thanks

Comment: In laravel 5.4, there is no `postLogin` method.

Comment: @PankitGami you can create your your own /login route and then use this method to login user

Comment: Yup definetly we can but than we won't get throttle restriction and all that. Login method of laravel comes with Throttling and other checks.

I suggest to use `authenticated` hook of `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

Answer (score 2):

Put this functions in your LoginController

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $user=User::whereEmail($credentials['email'] )->first();
    if (!empty($user) && $user->active) {
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        } else {
            return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors(['email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]
                );
        }
    } else {
        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors(['email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]
            );
    }
}

public function loginPath()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'loginTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/login';
}


protected function getFailedLoginMessage()
{
    return Lang::has('auth.failed')
        ? Lang::get('auth.failed')
        : 'set here your custom message.';
}
```